# I'm trying to update my self.health string every time the player collides with the cat enemy in Ursina, how do I do that?

Tags: ursina

The way I want to do that is draw a ray from Player() to the cat which is meow.Meow, and then update the text on screen every time the player collides with the cat.

```
class Player(Entity):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(collider="box")
    self.position = (0, 5, 0)
    self.collider = 'box'
    self.height = 2
    self.speed = 5
    self.gravity = 10
    self.y_velocity = 0
    self.jump_velocity = 5
    self.on_ground = True
    self.sprint_speed_modifier = 2
    self.interact_distance = 5
    self.shooting = False
    self.last_shot = time.time()
    self.mouse_sensitivity = Vec2(40, 40)

    self.crosshair = Entity(parent=camera.ui, model='quad', color=color.white, scale=0.008, rotation_z=45)
    self.camera_parent = Entity(parent=self, y=self.height)
    self.inventory = Inventory(
        Weapon(self.camera_parent, 0.25, (0.25, -0.25, 0.30), 180, 5, 20, True, 40, 0.25, 5, model='tommygun',
               texture='tommygun'))
    # self.weapon = Entity(parent=self.camera_parent, model='tommygun', texture='tommygun', position=(0.75, -0.95, 1), rotation_y=180)
    self.health = 1000

    camera.parent = self.camera_parent
    camera.position = (0, 0, 0)
    camera.rotation = (0, 0, 0)
    camera.fov = 90
    mouse.locked = True
    global player_instance
    player_instance = self

    def tealth():
        self.health -= 10

        if isinstance(Player, meow.Meow):
            tealth()
```

above is the local player class that I am doing that in.

Comment: You should make it cleared what you want to archive. Please post a minimal reproducable example and any error you may got.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Entity's `update()` function here is its implementation in your code:

```
class Player(Entity):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(collider="box")
    self.position = (0, 5, 0)
    self.collider = 'box'
    self.height = 2
    self.speed = 5
    self.gravity = 10
    self.y_velocity = 0
    self.jump_velocity = 5
    self.on_ground = True
    self.sprint_speed_modifier = 2
    self.interact_distance = 5
    self.shooting = False
    self.last_shot = time.time()
    self.mouse_sensitivity = Vec2(40, 40)

    self.crosshair = Entity(parent=camera.ui, model='quad', color=color.white, scale=0.008, rotation_z=45)
    self.camera_parent = Entity(parent=self, y=self.height)
    self.inventory = Inventory(
        Weapon(self.camera_parent, 0.25, (0.25, -0.25, 0.30), 180, 5, 20, True, 40, 0.25, 5, model='tommygun',
            texture='tommygun'))
    # self.weapon = Entity(parent=self.camera_parent, model='tommygun', texture='tommygun', position=(0.75, -0.95, 1), rotation_y=180)
    self.health = 1000

    camera.parent = self.camera_parent
    camera.position = (0, 0, 0)
    camera.rotation = (0, 0, 0)
    camera.fov = 90
    mouse.locked = True
    global player_instance
    player_instance = self

    def tealth(self):
        self.health -= 10

    def update(self):
        if isinstance(Player, meow.Meow):
            self.tealth()
```